# jQuery tokeninput create new textbox automatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-tokeninput

I am using jQuery tokeninput plugin in my Razor MVC5 view and it is working fine for searching data from database but I am facing one issue.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.code, new { id = "diag", @class = "diag " })
```

and tokeninput is attached to the class "diag" as

```
$(".diag").tokenInput("@Url.Action("Search", "approval")");
```

so it is working fine for all the input having class diag. But if you select the value searched it automatically create another texbox in next line. I searched a lot for a solution.

Has anyone come across an issue like this? Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you put action code? or sample ?

Comment: Hi problem solved. I added them as facebook.css and given token limit as 1 now

Answer (score 1):

I think this is css related issue.you need to use the tokeninput css.

```
<link href="your path/token-input.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```